# Fixing a kindle fire X43Z60

Tags: boot-loop, boot, unbricking, amazon-kindle-fire

So I have a Kindle Fire. One day I was stupid and deleted a bunch of stuff in the /system folder. Now, it no longer boots. No ADB, no fastboot, no nothing.

However, it still shows the ***static*** boot screen (with the orange 'fire' text.)

It never moves to the animated boot screen.

Can I get it into fastboot without a cable, or can I get into recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

Without the original Kindle cable you will not be able to get it into fastboot/recovery mode,

If you'd like more information and even some suggestions on what you might like to try next to see if you can rescue this device, head over to xda developers forum on the Kindle Fire

https://forum.xda-developers.com/kindle-fire-hd

Answer (score -1):

Put the device in fast boot mode: <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume up</kbd> buttons.

Select recovery option, then select safe recovery option.